# Added new user, but can't access account - public key encryption

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, useradd

I added a new user to one of our servers, but can't log in to it via putty. The error message is "Server refused our key", and from putty, "Disconnected: no supported authentication methods available (server sent: public key). Putty is set up to use a putty private key (.ppk file) to access the server. I looked in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, but didn't find anything specifying the user. Any ideas?

Comment: When you created the key, did you append the public key into the authorized_keys file?

Comment: I didn't create the key, it was created by someone who's no longer here. I checked and there is no "authorized_key" file set up in /etc/ssh. Ideally, I'd want to add a new user, give it access using the existing key, then delete or disable the old user.

Comment: If i were you, i would delete the key and create a new one. You don't know if the person that is no longer "here" still has the private key..

Comment: Unless you or "someone" changed the configuration, `authorized_keys` is in subdirectory `.ssh` in the home directory *of the userid* being logged-in. Like many ssh files, it must have permissions set to limit access (usually rw------- or rwx------) or it won't be used. Remember anything beginning with `.` is omitted by default in `ls` or `echo *` or such, so don't be confused by that.

Comment: @ryekayo - I'm trying to avoid that. The servers are on Amazon and I *think* I have to recreate the servers to do it.

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend cloning the stack and then it should provide you with a new key.